# JPanelMenu does not create the JPanelMenu-Menu class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jpanelmenu

The JpanelMenu will not create the additional class and I can't figure out why.

I placed linked to the site with this HEAD

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js"></script>
```

I then placed the script to enable the sidebar directly underneath it in the HEAD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
        jPM.on();
    });
</script>
```

I then placed the code for the nav within the HEADER

```
        <a class="menu-trigger" href="#menu">Click Me</a>
    <ul id="menu" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

But then when I run the page inspector, the "click me" works and opens but the sidebar is empty. It will NOT create the following class:

```
<ul id="jPanelMenu-menu" style="width: 250px; display: block; z-index: 1;">...</ul>
```

I think there may be something wrong within my CSS but I do not have any elements created for JPanel Menu but I do have a left and right panel within the body like so:

```
body {
height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 960px;
min-height: 600px;}

right-panel, .left-panel {
height: 100%;
min-height: 600px;}

.left-panel {
background: url('Images/side-bar-parchment.png') no-repeat fixed center;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
width: 170px;
z-index: 1;}

.right-panel {
    margin-left: 170px;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;}
```

Comment: Is it a purely `JavaScript` question? Or is `Java` involved as well?

Comment: DO you see any errors in the browser console?  Seeme like it is working here? http://jsfiddle.net/eLfLX/

Comment: I don't get it. It will display slide the screen across and perform the way it is supposed to, but the text within the side bar is not showing up! There are no errors in my browser console.

Comment: Added `jPanelMenu` so that it not confused with `Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I am not exactly sure how it got fixed but I decided to update the jQuery package to 2.0 from 1.8 and now it works! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

write a div in last of html or before html with same id.
1. Jpanelmenu should create it automatically but it does not.

```
<div id="jPanelMenu-menu"/> this will work.
```

and might be your html element is not enclosed  properly.